# Php Sub Category loop html

Tags: php, html, pdo

I get the data from the database. but I can not write between li,ul html tags.There is a problem in the loop. How do I write between li ul categories and subcategories. I have this pdo mysql category function.

```
<?php 
  ...
    function kategoriVer($ustid=0){

    $result = DB::get('SELECT * FROM urunler_kategori WHERE kategori_k='.$ustid.'');


    echo '<ul class="drop-down">';

    foreach($result as $kategori){

       echo '<li class="drop">
       <a href="#">'.$kategori->baslik_k.'</a>'; 

       kategoriVer($kategori->id_k);
    }
    echo '</li></ul>';

    }      

    kategoriVer();
?>
```

output html:

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
   <li class="menuparent">
      <a href="#">Çadırlar</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
         <li class="menuparent"><a href="#">Hi-Tech Çadırlar</a><ul class="sub-menu"></li></ul>
         <li class="menuparent"><a href="#">Çelik Konstrüksiyon</a><ul class="sub-menu"></li></ul>
         <li class="menuparent"><a href="#">Tribün Çadırlar</a><ul class="sub-menu"></li></ul>
         <li class="menuparent"><a href="#">Yürüyüş Yolları</a><ul class="sub-menu"></li></ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   <li class="menuparent"><a href="#">Şemsiyeler</a><ul class="sub-menu"></li></ul>
   <li class="menuparent"><a href="#">İklimlendirme</a><ul class="sub-menu"></li></ul>


   </li>
</ul>
```

i want this output:

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
     <li class="menuparent">
                <a href="#">Headers</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="header-standard.html">Standard</a></li>
                    <li><a href="header-no-topbar.html">No Topbar</a></li>
                    <li><a href="header-social-icons.html">Social Icons</a></li>
                    <li><a href="header-minimal.html">Minimal</a></li>
                    <li><a href="header-classic.html">Classic</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Can you show your output array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested 'for' loops in PHP to create hierarchical unordered list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142411/nested-for-loops-in-php-to-create-hierarchical-unordered-list)

Comment: It might not be the same question, but you have the [same answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15143016/4233593)